# Copy a file - Windows style

Tags: code-golf

This challenge is inspired by [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/612/):

[image]

### Challenge:

You'll simulate the copying a large file (1 Gigabyte). The transfer rate will vary between 10 kB/second to 100 MB/second.
Your task is to output the time remaining of the file transfer. The output should look like:

```
Time remaining: 03:12    (meaning it's 3 minutes and 12 seconds left)
Time remaining: 123:12   (meaning it's 2 hours, 3 minutes and 12 seconds left)
Time remaining: 02:03:12 (optional output, meaning the same as above)
```

Leading zeros need not be displayed for minutes and hours (optional), but must be shown for seconds. Showing the time remaining using only seconds is not OK.

**The file transfer:**

- The transfer rate will start at 10 MB/second.
- Every second, there will be a 30% chance that the transfer rate will change
- The new transfer rate should be picked randomly (uniform distribution) in the range `[10 kB/s, 100 MB/s]`, in steps of 10 kB/s.

**Note: You don't need to actually copy a file.**

You may choose to use: `1 GB = 1000 MB, 1 MB = 1000 kB, 1 kB = 1000 B`, or `1 GB = 1024 MB, 1 MB = 1024 kB, 1 kB = 1024 B`.

**Output:**

- You start at `01:40`, not `01:39`.
- You display the time after the transfer rate changes, but before anything is transferred at that rate
- The seconds should be displayed as integers, not decimals. It's optional to round up/down/closest.
- You should clear the screen every second, unless that's impossible in your language.
- The output should be constant: `Time remaining: 00:00` when the file transfer is over.

**Example:**

I have rounded up all decimal seconds. 
Assume the lines below are shown with 1 second in between, and the screen is cleared between each one:

```
Time remaining: 01:40  (Transfer rate: 10 MB/s)
Time remaining: 01:39      1 GB - 10 MB
Time remaining: 01:38      1 GB - 2*10 MB
Time remaining: 01:37      1 GB - 3*10 MB
Time remaining: 01:28:54   1 GB - 4*10 MB  (TR: 180 kB/s)
Time remaining: 01:28:53   1 GB - 4*10 MB - 180 kB
Time remaining: 01:28:52   1 GB - 4*10 MB - 2*180 kB  
Time remaining: 00:13      1 GB - 4*10 MB - 3*180 kB  (TR: 75 MB/s)
Time remaining: 00:12      1 GB - 4*10 MB - 3*180 kB - 75 MB
Time remaining: 00:11      1 GB - 4*10 MB - 3*180 kB - 2*75 MB
Time remaining: 00:10      1 GB - 4*10 MB - 3*180 kB - 3*75 MB
Time remaining: 00:09      1 GB - 4*10 MB - 3*180 kB - 4*75 MB
Time remaining: 00:08      1 GB - 4*10 MB - 3*180 kB - 5*75 MB
Time remaining: 14:09:06   1 GB - 4*10 MB - 3*180 kB - 6*75 MB  (TR: 10 kB/s)
Time remaining: 14:09:05   1 GB - 4*10 MB - 3*180 kB - 6*75 MB - 10 kB
Time remaining: 00:06      1 GB - 4*10 MB - 3*180 kB - 6*75 MB - 20 kB  (TR: 88.110 MB/s)
Time remaining: 00:05
Time remaining: 00:04
Time remaining: 00:03
Time remaining: 00:02
Time remaining: 00:01
Time remaining: 00:00     <- Transfer is finished. Display this.
```

Comment: You should put the XKCD tool-tip text below the image. Save people the time of having to look it up themselves.

Comment: @mbomb007, hover the image :)

Comment: Should that be, "you start at `1:40` (or `1:42`) not `1:39` (or `1:41`)"?

Comment: Also if we are using the `1024` version, what are the step sizes we should be using?

Comment: If hours remaining is zero, can we leave output as `00:00:10` for example?

Comment: @JonathanAllan, First comment: yes. Second comment, 10 kB (10240 bytes).

Comment: @AdmBorkBork, yes. 00:00:10 is OK.

Comment: How can I display "1:40" at the beginning if I do my displays *after* the rate change?

Comment: @Maltysen the rate changes from `0` to `10 Mb/s` at `t=0`. The rate is 10 the first second.

Comment: Is erasing the *line* sufficient?

Comment: @JonasWielicki, I don't understand what you mean...? Is erasing a line different from clearing it?

Comment: @StewieGriffin You ask for clearing the screen, which is, in terminal emulators, different from erasing the line. The screen may have previous history and the previous prompt on it.

Comment: Then yes, erasing the line is ok :-)

Comment: "*Leading zeros need not be displayed for minutes and hours (optional), but must be shown for seconds.*" So `2:3:12` is also acceptable? That looks weird.

Comment: @StewieGriffin is http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109608/63187 ok?

Comment: @ChristopherPeart, I'm afraid not.

Answer (score 9):

## Pyth - <s>70</s> 68 bytes

```
K^T5J^T3W>KZ%." r3úBTêî¢¤;¥
í".D/KJ60=J?<OT3O^T4J=-KJ.d1.
```

[Try it online without sleeps](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=K%5ET5J%5ET3W%3EKZ%25.%22+r%04%1B%133%C2%92%17%C3%BABT%C3%AA%C2%9A%C3%AE%C2%A2%C2%97%0F%C2%A4%3B%C2%A5%0A%01%C3%AD%05%14%22.D%2FKJ60%3DJ%3F%3COT3O%5ET4J%3D-KJ&debug=0).

Comment: @DigitalTrauma sorry, was using Luis' answer as a guide ._.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma fixed.

Comment: Lol. When porting from (golfing) language A to (golfing) language B is easier than reading the spec ;-)

Comment: @Maltysen Sorry about that! :-)

Comment: @DigitalTrauma forgot to take out the sleeps on the updated link. fixed now

Comment: Can you give an explanation of what the heck is going on here?

Comment: Code doesn't always display 0:00 at the end.

Answer (score 8):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>190</s> <s>215</s> 187 bytes

```powershell
($t="Time remaining: ")+"00:01:42";for($f,$r=1gb,10mb;$f-gt0;$f-=$r){if((Random 10)-lt3){$r=(Random -mi 1kb -ma (10mb+1))*10}$t+[Timespan]::FromSeconds([int]($f/$r));sleep 1}$t+"00:00:00"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#NU69CsMgGHwVEQdtIvVrOxmy9gHabiGDSUwqjRqMW@hjd061UDg4OO5vpyTW@GGsRkFbZZxxk0SYFVgIKUBeTrgafaBkLEmoYepKELaryMinKDLVJLDNjJTelBu8RSAYn@OZbcn@17g1CF5dYoVozhfA2AHEm8Siydvrolwr5TV4e9e9d8NKG@Nim2aPqZ9V66z1giAHfscy8L5/nOe96p/6Cw) (TIO doesn't support clearing screen between lines)

Sets our initial `$f`ile size and our initial transfer `$r`ate to `1gb` and `10mb`/s, respectively. Then, so long as we still have `$f`ile remaining, we loop.

Inside the loop, the `if` selects a number from `0` to `9` inclusive, and if it's 0, 1, or 2 (i.e., 30% of the time), we change the rate. This picks a random integer between `1kb` and `10mb` then that's multiplied by `10` to get our step count.

We then leverage the `FromSeconds` [static method](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromseconds(v=VS.85).aspx) from the `TimeSpan` .NET library to construct the time remaining. The output format of that call exactly matches the challenge requirements, so no need for additional formatting.

*(Saved a bunch thanks to @ConnorLSW)*

Comment: @StewieGriffin TIO has output caching. Select "disable output cache" in the Settings drawer, and it gives different results.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but the `-f` operator doesn't appear to do anything. By taking that out and using `for` loop instead of `while`, and then changing both instances of `get-date` to `date`, I was able to shave off 22 bytes. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#VY5NDoIwEIWvMiFdtEqhozsJl1AvUOgUG2lrCjvk2K6xxJWrL3kv72ezMXFmS5ZaHLoSle8aZuUwqx0tS2JxlnOsKlTvqw4meiFHOoslJ/hPAOkd4LPL1MD3iiMKcUC1FnfnCRJ57YILwwWKI@dGzwSnGmulRKWNuVEfg5nyizrPyT9fNNNI9AJct@0Toux1/6Av "PowerShell – TIO Nexus")

Comment: @briantist TIO requires `Get-Date` because otherwise it uses the Linux `date` command, which is different. You can drop it on Windows because PowerShell wraps the Windows `date` command. But, thanks for the `for` loop construction!

Comment: @AdmBorkBork yeah I noticed that, but in a stock Windows environment it would work. I wonder if it's acceptable to just put `nal date get-date` in the header in TIO?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork and on windows it doesn't wrap the windows date command, it just ignores it because it's not an .exe on windows, so it falls back to the same behavior as `random` (try the command with `get-` prepended if all else fails).

Comment: @briantist Dennis has updated TIO to also have an alias for `date` to be `Get-Date`, so it will now work without the `Get-`. I'm going to leave this answer as-is so that it's still competing. Thanks!

Comment: @AdmBorkBork woah very nice! Thanks Dennis.

Comment: tried to cut down on parts of this, pretty sure i'm missing something in the rules though, can someone tell me why `$s=1GB;$t=10kb;do{$t=($t,(random -mi 10kb -ma 100mb))[(random 10)-lt3];($a="Time Remaining ")+[Timespan]::FromSeconds(($s-=$t)/$t).ToString("hh\:mm\:ss");sleep 1;cls;}while($s-gt0);$a+"00:00:00"` is invalid?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork `Random 10` includes `0` but not `10`, so i use `-lt` instead of `-le` should that not give the same effect? is there any issue with `[Timespan]::FromSeconds(x).ToString("hh\:mm\:ss‌​")`?

Comment: @ConnorLSW Don't need the special formatting, as the default output matches the challenge specificiations. I took that and the `Random` (sorry for my fencepost error) and merged the changes in, saving almost 30 bytes. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, glad to get PowerShell higher on the list where possible :)

Comment: @AdmBorkBork I don't think the `[int]` cast is required anymore either.

Comment: @ConnorLSW [Removing it](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#NU5PC8IgHP0qIh60TfJXnRy79gGqW3Rwmy5p6nDeRh@789IgePDg8f5tlKQW36zTKGqnrLd@lAizCgshBcjTATcmREpMTWILY1eDcF1DDB@TKNSSyFZrKL0oPwSHQDA@pSNbs/2vcWcRvLrMCtGSr4CxHYg3SdW9bC@z8g8pzzG4q@6DH5Y8uM/NzTJpPSMozt@jArxtHx94r/qn/gI) results in milliseconds being tacked on as decimals.

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 78 bytes

*Thanks to [@Maltysen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31343/maltysen) and [@DigitalTrauma](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11259/digital-trauma) for corrections.*

```
1e5 1e3`XK10&XxyXIy/t0>*12L/'MM:SS'XO'Time remaining: 'whD-r.3<?1e4Yr}K]I0>]xx
```

Try it at [MATL Online!](https://matl.io/?code=1e5+1e3%60XK10%26XxyXIy%2Ft0%3E%2a12L%2F%27MM%3ASS%27XO%27Time+remaining%3A+%27whD-r.3%3C%3F1e4Yr%7DK%5DI0%3E%5Dxx&inputs=&version=19.7.4) (you may need to press "Run" several times if it doesn't initially work).

The online interpreter times out after 30 seconds. You may want to change `10` (pause time in tenths of second) to something smaller [such as `3`](https://matl.io/?code=1e5+1e3%60XK3%26XxyXIy%2Ft0%3E%2a12L%2F%27MM%3ASS%27XO%27Time+remaining%3A+%27whD-r.3%3C%3F1e4Yr%7DK%5DI0%3E%5Dxx&inputs=&version=19.7.4) in order to increase speed of display

#### Explanation

```
1e5                  % Push 1e5: file size in 10-kB units
1e3                  % Push 1e3: initial rate in 10-kB/s units
`                    % Do...while
  XK                 %   Copy current rate into clipboard K (doesn't consume it)
  10&Xx              %   Wait 1 second and clear screen
  y                  %   Duplicate current file size onto the top of the stack
  XI                 %   Copy it to clipboard I (doesn't consume it)
  y                  %   Duplicate current rate onto the top of the stack
  /                  %   Divide. This gives the estimated remaining time in seconds
                     %   It may be negative in the last iteration, because the
                     %   "remaining" file size may have become negative
  t0>*               %   If negative, convert to 0
  12L/               %   Push 86400 and divide, to convert from seconds to days
  'MM:SS'XO          %   Format as a MM:SS string, rounding down
  'Time remaining: ' %   Push this string
  wh                 %   Swap, concatenate
  D                  %   Display
  -                  %   Subtract. This gives the new remaining file size
  r                  %   Push random number uniformly distributed in (0,1)
  .3<                %   Is it less than 0.3?
  ?                  %   If so
    1e4Yr            %     Random integer between 1 and 1e4. This is the new rate 
                     %     in 10-kB/s units
  }                  %   Else
    K                %     Push rate that was copied into clipboard K
  ]                  %   End
  I                  %   Push previous remaining file size from clipboard I
  0>                 %   Is it positive?
]                    % End. If top of the stack is true: next iteration
xx                   % Delete the two numbers that are on the stack
```

Comment: I don't understand MATL, but it looks to me as if you're always getting a new rate instead of only 30% of the time from your explanation.

Comment: @Maltysen Corrected now. Thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, <s>116</s> 110 bytes

[Try it online, except repl.it reads `\r` as a newline and also can't use `$><<` so it's replaced with its 5-byte equivalent, `print`.](https://repl.it/F56D)

Shoutout to JonasWielicki for the initial idea of using `\r` to reset the line.

```
f=1e5;r=1e3;(k=f/r=rand<0.3?1+rand(1e4):r;$><<"\rTime remaining: %02d:%02d"%[k/60,k%60];f-=r;sleep 1)while f>0
```

This version is untested on Windows, but works on Unix.

Answer (score 4):

## Bash + common utils, 117

Straightforward implementation.  A few bytes saved by dividing out by 10000:

```bash
for((b=10**5,r=1000;b>0;r=RANDOM%10<3?RANDOM%10000+1:r,b-=r));{
clear
date -ud@$[b/r] "+Time remaining: %T"
sleep 1
}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@WX6ShkWRraKClZapTBKQNDKyT7Aysi2yDHP1c/H1VDQ1sjO3hbCDQNrQq0knStS3S1LSu5krOSU0s4kpJLElV0C1NcVCJTtIvilVQ0g7JzE1VKErNTczMy8xLt1JQDVHiKs5JTS1QMOCq/f//a16@bnJickYqAA). Using `sleep 0` on the TIO so you don't have to wait.  `clear` doesn't work on TIO.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 162 bytes

Shows minutes as is with padded seconds (floored)

E.g., `123:45`

```js
t=1e5
s=1e3
setInterval(c=>c.log(`Time remaining: ${c.clear(d=t/s),d/60|0}:`+`0${t-=s>t?t:s,r=Math.random,s=r()<0.3?1+r()*1e4|0:s,d%60|0}`.slice(-2)),1e3,console)
```

Comment: I think you forgot to shorten `console.clear` to `c.clear` ;-) That's a great idea, BTW

Comment: @ETHproductions Ooooops! Thanks :)

Comment: You could get this down to 154 bytes by adding HTML - `<input id=o>` - and making a couple of other adjustments: `t=1e5;i=s=1e3;setInterval(_=>o.value=\`Time remaining: ${(d=t/s)/60|0}:\`+\`0${t-=s>t?t:s,r=Math.random(),s=r<.3?1+r*1e4|0:s,d%60|0}\`.slice(-2),i)`

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3.6 (<s>212</s> 203 bytes)

```
from random import*
import time,datetime
r=1e7
d=1e9
while 1:
 print(f"\x1b[KTime remaining: {datetime.timedelta(seconds=d//r)}",end="\r");d=max(0,d-r);time.sleep(1)
 if random()>.7:r=randint(1,1e4)*1e4
```

Pretty straightforward, I think. Erases the line using ANSI escape sequence and `K` command.

- Saved 9 bytes thanks to [@ValueInk](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/108976/copy-a-file-windows-style/109026?noredirect=1#comment265544_109026)

Comment: Skip a space in your first line with `from random import*`. `d//r` is shorter than `int(d/r)`. Also, might as well go with `r=1e7;d=1e9` from the start.

Comment: @ValueInk Right, didn’t think of 1eX for r and d because I wanted them to be integers; when I shortened the randint line, I forgot about that ... :)

Answer (score 1):

### C <s>184</s> <s>171</s> 155 bytes

```
f(){i,j=0,r=1e7;for(i=1e9;i>0;i-=r){j=i/r;printf("Time remaining: %02d:%02d:%02d\r",j/3600,(j/60)%60,j%60);sleep(1);if(rand()%10<3)r=(rand()%10000)*1e4;}}
```

I hope this qualifies.

Ungolfed version:

```
void f()
{
    int j=0;
    float rate=1e7; 
    for(int size=1e9;i>0; size-=rate)
    {     
       j=size/rate;      
       printf("Time remaining: %02d:%02d:%02d\r",j/3600,(j/60)%60,j%60);
       sleep(1);

       if(rand()%10<3)
          rate=(rand()%10000)*1e4;          



   }

}
```

Explanation: In the golfed version `i` corresponds to `size` in ungolfed version and `r` is `rate` in ungolfed version. `j` stores the time remaining in seconds.

- I have 10^9 bytes to copy. I start copying at the rate of 10 Megabytes/second,
- If the probablity is less than 30% , change the rate (from 10 kilobytes to 100 Megabytes per second)

@ValueInk Thanks for saving 13 bytes.

@nmjcman101 Thanks for saving 16 bytes.

Comment: This doesn't look like it actually does what the challenge says. Can you explain how it works?

Comment: It just simulates time output, i have not figured out how to do the data transfer part. Guess I'm gonna put this on hold until then.

Comment: You don't change the rate after 3 iterations. It has a 30% chance of changing. So you probably want to do something similar to the following: `if(rand()%10<3)r=(rand()%10000+1)*1e4;` (Especially since the minimum rate is 10 kB/s, not 1MB/s like your solution is saying, and the rate chance should be a somewhat uniform distribution.)

Comment: @ValueInk Thanks so much. :) Updated. Gets the work done! I did not know how exactly to simulate the 30% probability part. So much clearer now.

Comment: you can golf `j/3600,(j/60)%60,j%60` (21)  with `s=60;` and  `j/s/s,j/s%s,j%s` (20)

Comment: Additionally, you can get rid of `system("clear");` by putting a `\r` at the end of your `printf` and removing the `\n` at the beginning.
You can also put the `i-=r` inside of the for loop, after the second `;`

Comment: @nmjcman101 I have done carriage return in one or some of my other solutions as well, but this time somehow on my terminal, putting `\r` did not work, I could not see anything.

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 193 bytes

```
@set/ap=10000,s=p*10,r=p/10
:l
@set/at=s/r,m=t/60,n=t%%60+100,s-=r
@cls
@echo Time remaining: %m%:%n:~1%
@timeout/t>nul 1
@if %random:~-1% lss 3 set/ar=%random%%%p+1
@if %t% gtr 0 goto l
```

Note: Slight bias towards rates of 27.68 MB/s or less.